# How to write from a linux boot cd to a usb with a mac

Tags: linux, macos, boot, usb

I bought a book about C and it comes with a livecd of a custom distro with scripts pre-loaded. My quandary is that my current macbook pro was not equipped with a disk drive. I have temporary access to a Mac with a drive. How can I write the file from the cd to the usb so I can boot my mac? Can I write it directly from the disk, or do I need to convert it to an iso first? I am comfortable using the terminal, and do already know how to write an iso to a usb using `dd if=`and `of=`. The usb is also already properly formatted.

Comment: Some distros will work if you use 'dd' to copy the image to a USB. It would be dd if=nameofCD of=nameofUSB

Comment: If the LiveCD is a hybrid ISO image, then it can be copied directly to a USB flash drive.  See http://superuser.com/questions/683210/how-do-i-determine-if-an-iso-is-a-hybrid/683232#683232

Comment: Sadly this has not worked.

Comment: Check out this fourm: http://superuser.com/questions/85987/mac-os-x-best-way-to-make-an-iso-from-a-cd-or-dvd